# Insert svg into another svg using Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael

I am a little stuck with what might be a trivial question:

I have two Raphael canvas on my site, following a certain event I need to take the content of the one canvas and add it (with a different scale and position) to the second canvas.

How do I even approach that task?

Answer (score 0):

Just to render this question maybe a wee bit useful, I by now succeeded.

I've gathered up all elements from the one paper (with the forEach-method) and pushed them into a set.

That set I cloned to the other paper using Shamasis' .cloneToPaper(targetPaper) method from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687873/raphaeljs-copy-element-or-set-to-another-paper).

So it turned out to be fairly simply if one were to enter the right search terms >.>